# Where is cd ~ located on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, cd-command, tilde

What is the absolute path of `cd ~` on Ubuntu?

Trying to find out where this `dir` is located?

For example:

```
/home
```

Comment: after entering `cd ~` enter `pwd` to find out.

Comment: @shiftas thanks that works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally on linux it is `/home/<your-username>/`. You can see the path of the current directory if you enter `pwd` while you are in it.

Comment: thank you 'pwd' is exactly what I needed cheers - will accept your answer.

Answer (score 7):

`cd ~` takes you to your home directory. By default, the home directory is determined by the information stored in the “passwd” database (typically `/etc/passwd` on basic desktop systems, but central databases are often used in enterprise setups). However in a shell, `cd ~` (and [`cd` with no argument](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cd.html)) looks at the value of the `HOME` variable, so a user’s home directory can be overridden (as far as the shell is concerned) by changing that variable. The `HOME` variable [is initialised to point to the user’s home directory](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html#tag_08_03). If `HOME` is unset, `cd ~` will revert to the default home directory (and `cd` will fail, at least in bash).

The canonical way to determine what a given user’s home directory is, before login, is to use `getent`:

```
getent passwd user
```

will show `user`’s entry in the database, and the home directory is the sixth field:

```
getent passwd user | cut -d: -f6
```

Answer (score 5):

Usually, the `HOME` environment variable will tell you what the home directory is set to, for whichever user is logged in. I.e.:

`echo $HOME`

However, if the `HOME` variable is not set (from `info bash`):

```
If 'HOME' is unset, the home
directory of the user executing the shell is substituted instead.
```

You can find more information about Tilde Expansion in the `info bash` manual.

Answer (score 1):

In quite all shells (e.g. `*sh`, `*csh`, `*ksh`), `~` is a shortcut for *the current user home directory*.

Many shells use `HOME` environment variable to "cache" the position of the home directory. The initial value of `HOME` is read from `/etc/passwd` file.

As @Time4Tea stated, the best way to check the current position of `~` is to print the `HOME` variable. E.g. `echo $HOME`.

Remember that the value of this variable is user dependant and that the user can change it if he needs.

Last but not least, shells usually support also the `~username` shortcuts. E.g. `~andcoz` is my (andcoz) home and not the current user's one.